# GCP Can't Connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform

This is my first attempt at deploying a Node.js application on a Google VM instance while connecting to MongoDB.

In MongoDB, I have whitelisted my IP address and the VM instance's IP address. When I start my server using Google Cloud Shell, I receive the following error:

```
op.cb(new error_1.MongoNetworkError(`connection ${this.id} to ${this.address} closed`));
      ^
MongoNetworkError: connection 1 to 34.71.95.215:27017 closed
```

I'm connecting on port 8080. The external IP is listed on my GCP instance page and when I ping it, it is up. IP: 34.68.254.120

When I whitelist 0.0.0.0/0 in Mongodb, the code runs successfully, and I can preview my app through GCP.

I created a new instance from scratch, and it also crashes with the same error.

ETA: In looking at the source code around the error message at:
...\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js
it looks like a closed connection. The error message above spits out the IP address as the Iowa Google Data Center where my VM is housed.

I don't know what this means, but if you do, please let me know.

ETA2: I have 2 problems, and they may be connected. The first is that my VM server cannot connect to MongoDB. This should be simple -- whitelist the external IP address of my VM server. It does not work (I have to open MongoDB to 0.0.0.0/0 for it to connect).

The second is that I cannot connect to my server via the external IP address, regardless of whether MongoDB is connected or not. It "refuses to connect." I can do a web preview of my running server, though.

It seems the two may be connected somehow. I've rebooted my VM, but it did not fix anything. I whitelisted the error message IP address in MongoDB, but it did not help.

ETA3: Okay, it appears I have solved the whitelist to MongoDB issues. Through Cloud Shell, I asked my VM what the IP is. It is different than the one GCP tells me is the external IP. By adding this IP to the whitelist, I can connect between GCP VM and MongoDB. Whew. No idea why.

The VM's external IP address through my browser still gives me a cannot connect message, and when I use the new VM IP address I found through Cloud Shell, it gives me a "took too long to respond" message.

So I feel I have made progress. The remaining problem is accessing my server through Chrome.

Any suggestions on how I can investigate the issue further? I'm at a dead end. I believe the problem is likely simple given my inexperience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by a friend, for anyone in the future with this issue.

I had set up my GCP VM using Cloud Shell. I had housed my code by coping my repository through Cloud Shell. It turns out, this is more of a virtual interface with my VM, and the files are not physically on my VM. I needed to go through SSH, clone my repository there, and run my server through SSH. Cloud Shell was causing the problem.